# How to run rsync without staying logged in?

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-12.04, migration, nohup

I want to run the following rsync command to transfer a folder from a remote server to my current one `sudo -r -a -v -e 'ssh -p portnum' username@serverip:/home/path/* /home/path` this directory is quite large in both size and structure and the transfer takes some time. Rather than leave my computer turned on with the PuTTY window open, I would like to run a command that continues to execute after I have closed the window and shut down my PC.

I have tried using prefixing it with `nohup` but it didn't work. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 12):

Run the command within [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). Basically:

1. Install screen: `$ sudo apt-get install screen`
2. Run screen: `$ screen` ... at which point, you'll have a shell running from within screen.
3. Run your command.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>, which will detach you from the screen session and your command will continue running.

When you want to re-attach, just ssh in as the user who owns the screen session and then:

```
$ screen -RD
```

Comment: Should be accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could install and run a program like screen, or throw that command in a bash script and run it on cron one time.

Comment: I think this is what I need, could you elaborate?